# Philips Android TV 43PUT7791/v1 boot loop issue

Tags: android-tv, smart-tv, google-tv

I have Philips Android TV 43PUT7791/V7 which stuck at logo and rebooting continuously. I want to enter into recovery mode . I have tried with pressing and hold  down key and plugged the power and waited for 1 minute and also tried combination present in joystick keys.
Kindly, someone help me to enter into recovery mode.